# Handlebars Template Not Rendering Properly with Ember.js

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a simple Ember.js app that is using Handlebars templates. I have a few users routes as outlined in my main.js file below:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('users', function() {
    this.resource('user', { path: '/:user_id' }, function() {
      this.route('edit');
    });
    this.route('create');
  });
});


App.UsersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('user');
  }
});
App.UsersController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  sortProperties: ['first_name']
});    
App.UserRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('user', params.user_id);
  }
});
App.UserController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({});
```

To got with that, I have the below two templates (in the same file):

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="users">
  <ol class='breadcrumb'>
    <li>{{#link-to 'index'}}Home{{/link-to}}</li>
    <li class='active'>Users</li>
  </ol>

  <ul class='list-unstyled'>
    {{#each}}
      <li>{{#link-to 'user' this class='label label-primary'}}{{first_name}}{{/link-to}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="user">
  <ol class='breadcrumb'>
    <li>{{#link-to 'index'}}Home{{/link-to}}</li>
    <li class='active'>User: {{first_name}}</li>
  </ol>
  <p>Test</p>
</script>
```

However, the "user" template doesn't load. If I access "/users/4" it just loads the "users" template again. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have template hierarchy like this

```
application
  -index (generated)
  -users
     -index (generated)
     -user
        -index (generated)
        -edit
     -create
```

You have to tell the placeholder {{outlet}} in parent template where the child templates get rendered.

Assume we have two child templates and first child template get rendered in the area where {{outlet}} given, so navigating to second child template will replace the first child. But parent template content will be retained, only the area for child template will be changed.

Have a look at it

http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/

http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/rendering-with-helpers/

Comment: Ok, so I could create a "users" template with just an {{outlet}}, and then a "users/index" template that would render at "/users" and a "user" template that would be rendered at "users/:user_id"?

Comment: Yeah, just tried it and it works. Thanks for your help, it makes a lot more sense now that you've explained it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add an `{{outlet}}` to your `users` template so that it knows where the subroutes (in your case `user`) should be rendered.

Comment: What if I wanted the templates to be completely different though? If I add an {{outlet}}, won't it render everything in "users" in addition to what's in "user"?

Comment: Thanks Ryan - didn't fully understand it until Susai also answered, but you're right, I needed an {{outlet}}.